# XML mode for XEmacs?

Tags: xml, emacs, editing, xemacs

I'm a [GNU Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) user who uses [`nxml-mode`](http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode/) for editing XML files, but I have a colleague who would like to use [XEmacs](http://www.xemacs.org/) for editing XML files. It seems as though my colleague can't use `nxml-mode` because the `README` file for that package says:

> To use this, you need GNU Emacs version 21.x, preferably 21.3. GNU
>   Emacs version 20 will not work properly, nor will XEmacs

**What is a reasonable way to configure an XEmacs XML mode?** Does it ship with one, or are there nice add-ons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, XEmacs comes with `sgml-mode` and `psgml-mode`.
For more modes to edit XML, see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/XmlMode.

Answer (score 0):

I used PSGML mode via XEmacs for several years and it is excellent. No support for RELAX NG, but terrific for anything you can dig up a DTD for.